# Why is this CSS border not displayed?

Tags: css

I want to add a border to the footer.

Here are the css lines:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
clear: both; 
line-height: 1.36em;
padding: 08px 0px 0px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #fff;
border-top: 5px solid #4cb6cb;
```

What have I set wrong ? Think sometimes block the border to show.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="page_footer">
    <div id="bottom_nav">
        <a href="/about"><?php echo $LANG['footer-about']; ?></a>
        <a href="/terms"><?php echo $LANG['footer-terms']; ?></a>
        <a href="/support"><?php echo $LANG['footer-support']; ?></a>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="clear">
        <?php echo APP_TITLE; ?> © <?php echo APP_YEAR; ?>
        <a class="lang_link" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="App.getLanguageBox('<?php echo $LANG['page-language']; ?>'); return false;"><?php echo $LANG['lang-name']; ?></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add some HTML code that we can see how this behavior in the rest of your code

Comment: added, please check again. :)

Comment: @EsembledTrade Please include your CSS selector and not just the properties you're using. We don't know what element you're applying those styles to. Also please include the outputted, generated HTML, not the input PHP

Comment: @TylerH What selector ? #page_footer

Comment: @EsembledTrade If that's your selector, then yes. Right now you've only included the CSS *properties* you're using, but you haven't included the CSS *selector* that those properties are applied to. It could be that your problem is you are using a wrong/mistyped selector.

Answer (score 0):

You may be applying this in a wrong class or id. Your code is fine.
Try adding a rule for HEIGHT to the footer itself and checking the class name again.

```css
#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
clear: both; 
line-height: 1.36em;
padding: 08px 0px 0px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
background: #fff;
border-top: 5px solid #4cb6cb;
}
```

```html
<div id="page_footer">

        <div id="bottom_nav">
            <a href="/about">A link here></a>
            <a href="/terms">A link here</a>
            <a href="/support">A link here</a>
        </div>

        <div id="footer" class="clear">
            <?php echo APP_TITLE; ?> © <?php echo APP_YEAR; ?>
            <a class="lang_link" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="App.getLanguageBox('<?php echo $LANG['page-language']; ?>'); return false;"><?php echo $LANG['lang-name']; ?></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sure the class name it's the correct one. Already exist a rule for height. "line-height: 1.36em;"